# Connection refused between docker compose services

Tags: reactjs, flask, docker-compose

I have a hello-world react app (frontend) and a flask api (backend), each one is inside a docker container, I'm trying to make a request from the frontend to the backend, but i get a connection refused error.

Here are the related files related to the backend:

app.py

```py
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_data', methods=["GET"])
def get_data():
    return jsonify({'data': random.randint(0, 10)}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

requirements.txt

```
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
Flask==3.0.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app.py /app/app.py

CMD ["python", "app.py" ]
```

Here are the files related to the frontend:

The react app is the hello world created with `npx create-react-app frontend`

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /test-front/

COPY public/ /test-front/public
COPY src/ /test-front/src
COPY package.json /test-front/

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is the docker compose file:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    build: frontend/.
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app
  backend:
    build: backend/.
    expose:
      - "5000"
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
```

The flask api is running in the port 5000, and the react app is running in the port 3000.

The frontend app is making a request with axios to http://backend:5000/get_data, but for now I'm trying to reproduce the problem with commands in the container console.

Here is the problem: I enter the frontend container and try to make a request to /get_data from the backend, but i get a connection refused error:

```bash
myPC$ docker exec -it test_docker-frontend-1 bash
container$ curl -v http://backend:5000/get_data
```

Console output:

```bash
*   Trying 172.20.0.3:5000...
* connect to 172.20.0.3 port 5000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to backend port 5000 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend port 5000 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

What should I do to be able to make requests from the frontend container to the backend container?

I tried exposing the port 5000 and adding the "5000:5000" on the ports section in the backend service, but it didn't work. The frontend should be able to make requests to the backend container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **host** for exposing on python code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```